# Using Google Maps in Android - Error code

Tags: java, eclipse

i was trying to learn this tutorial. 
Using Google Maps in Android-http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

The first code that I did is :

```
package net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps;

    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity 
    {    
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Im getting a lot of error such as:

1) import.com.google cannot be resolved.
2) MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type.

Please help me. Thanks

**OK. I FOUND THE SOLUTION IN [Mapview in MapActivity Class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214091/mapview-in-mapactivity-class-not-found)**

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old/deprecated API which cannot be used now .
You Have to use the Google Maps V2 Api for development.
For this you need

1. Google Play services install in your SDK(**[Read this Post](http://mzubair.com/solving-the-problemserrors-of-google-maps-api-v2/)**).
2. API key from the Google API Console.
3. If you want to develop for android 2.2 (Froyo) and above you need to use the Supportmapfragment and fragmentActivity(**[Read This Post](http://mzubair.com/creating-an-android-app-with-maps-api-v2/)**).
4. If you want to develop for android 3.0(honeycomb) and above you have to use the Mapfragment and the Activity(**[Read This Post](http://mzubair.com/creating-an-android-app-with-maps-api-v2-for-minsdk11-android-23-0-honeycomb/)**).

**Please** Search the SO forum before posting a question there are a lot of solved Questions regarding the Same Issue